# What are the requirements for running .net application on windows ce5?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

What are the requirements for running .net framework targeted application on Windows CE 5?

If I try to start an application that I developed for Windows Mobile 6, I will get the following error.

> Cannot find 'Projectname' (or one of
>   its components) Make sure the path and
>   filename are correct and that all the
>   required libraries are available

My app is a simple hello world app. What could cause that such error message?

Is there a way to dertimine which .net compact framework version is running on my system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run **cgacutil**, which is in the Windows folder. It should give you a version number of the compact framework installed onto the device. It's likely you dont have the correct compact framework installed.

If you dont have cgacutil, its likely that compact framework isnt installed to the device at all. In this case download the latest version of the framework (currently 3.5, available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e3821449-3c6b-42f1-9fd9-0041345b3385&displaylang=en)). The install may take around 7MB of space from your main memory. If storage space is tight, it can be installed to external memory, with some potential consequences as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170506/is-it-worth-to-install-the-compact-framework-on-storage-card)

Comment: There is no cgacutil in the windows directory. So it seems there is no version of the compact framework currently installed?

Comment: Correct, its not installed at all!

Comment: That sucks. It seems that I only have 1MB of storage left on the internal storage. But I do have some space left on a SD card. I assume installing the compact framework on a SD card is no option?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can install CF to SD: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170506/is-it-worth-to-install-the-compact-framework-on-storage-card

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by what you're wondering... Which version of compact framework is installed in your system and, most of all, if there is a version of compact framework installed.
I suggest you to download the version corresponding to your developing environment and install it in your device.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Windows Mobile 5 comes with **.NET Compact Framework 1.0 SP3** pre-installed.

An application developed for Windows Mobile 6 is at least going to use **.NET Compact Framework 2.0 SP2**, therefore make sure that it is installed on the Windows Mobile 5 device.

You can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=aea55f2f-07b5-4a8c-8a44-b4e1b196d5c0&displaylang=en), but generally it is a good practice to install the latest version available, as long as it is supported by the device.

Comment: The question refers to **Windows CE5** and not to Windows Mobile 5